# Deleting dynamic char** in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, char

Disclosure: I'm trying to solve a challenge with strict time and memory limits. I would normally use vectors and strings, but here I need the fastest and smallest solution (with vectors it actually ran above the time limit), so I turned to dynamic arrays of char*.
The relevant parts of my code:

```
char** substrings(string s, int* n){
    *n = 0;
    ...
    ////////////////////////////////
    char** strings = new char*[*n];
    ////////////////////////////////
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < s.length() - i + 1; j++){
            ...
            strings[si] = tmp;
            ...
        }
    }
    return strings;
}

int main(){
    ...
    for (int ti = 0; ti < t; ti++){
        cin >> s;
        char** substr = substrings(s, &n);
        ...

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            delete substr[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Everything runs just fine without deleting the array (of arrays), but that is unacceptable, so how do I go about this? I've tried a lot of variations that seemed logical but I get runtime errors.

Comment: I think that low performance is due to your algorithm and not the use of `std::string` or `std::vector`.

Comment: you cannot do it faster than vector does because vector uses the same `new`, just preallocate vector memory by specifying number of items

Comment: Actually using chars instead of strings helped me get closer to the time limit with a few hundredths of a second. The problem with vectors I think was that the test cases added elements many thousands times, and the reallocation took too much time. I wanted to save time by allocating the memory only once, and that's why I used an array.

Comment: @b4kancs: it's why I suggested to preallocate the memory, in this case no reallocation will happen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is similar to allocating, but in reverse order, and using `delete[]` instead of `new[]`:

```
for(int i = 0; i <  LENGTH; i++) 
    delete[] strings[i]; // delete each pointer in char** strings
delete[] strings; // finally delete the array of pointers
```

I assumed here that `LENGTH` is the length of the array of pointers to `char*`. So it looks that you only perform the first round of de-allocation

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        delete substr[i]; // need delete[] substr[i] here
```

but with `delete` instead of `delete[]`, you need `delete[] substr[i]` instead, as my guess is that `substr[i]` is a `char*` pointer pointing the first element of an array of `char`s allocated by `new[]`. You finally need the additional

```
delete[] substr;
```

Comment: Hi, I actually tried this before, but I still get 'HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED' error. Also, isn't delete[] for deleting objects by calling their destructors? Here is my full code, maybe it will help: http://pasted.co/39f75c26

Comment: @b4kancs no, `delete[]` **always** tries to deallocate the memory for a dynamically allocated array. If the array consists of objects, then each object in the array will have its destructor called. In your case, your elements of the array are `char*` pointers, which have no destructors, and that's why you need the additional `delete[] substr[i]` in the first loop. Try the code I suggested, and if it's not working, make sure your `new` allocations are correct, i.e. make sure you allocate enough space for each substring (don't forget maybe about the `'\0'` string terminator).

Comment: You were right, the problem was, that my strings didn't have the terminating '0' byte at the end, so I guess the program tried to access 'wrong' memory. Interestingly, it still doesn't seem to work properly, at least I get hundreds of megabytes more memory usage, than before (with vectors, it ran with ~64000 KB, now it uses over ~350000).

Comment: @b4kancs try to debug your code and make absolutely sure you allocate the exact number of chars as needed, and not more. Use valgrind or some other profiler to see if you have leaks. If there are no leaks, then you allocate too much. Debugging is the answer ;)